# How can I match my desired data using mysql?

Tags: mysql

Hi guys again I have a problem in matching my data. What I want to do is to eliminate a data whenever there is a match found, but the thing is I don't know how.

For Example:

I have the values of the ff: and whenever they have a matched value it will not be returned. Could anyone help me on this. Thank you

```
Absent |  Day
1          1
2          1
1          2
2          3
1          1 3 5
3          2
3          2
2          1
1          1 0
```

so the returned value would be;

```
Absent | Day
2         1
1         2
2         3
3         2
3         2
2         1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean `Absent !=  Day`, if yes then you can simply add that condition in your `WHERE` clause like

```
select * from table1
where Absent !=  Day
```

Comment: This works only for those who have 1 data but it doesn't work when compared to 2 or more numbers like in the example 1 = 135 it doesn't eliminate it

Comment: @user3563036, first of all that's not at all a good table design. You should never have comma separated values in columns (which again defeats normalization) to avoid these kind of problems.

Comment: @user3563036, Yes it does eliminate those rows even. See this fiddle here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ddb4b/1. If the fiddle is not correct then edit your post accordingly and include table schema.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this query.

```
SELECT * FROM tab WHERE absent <> SUBSTR(day,1,1);
```

Here is the demo.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9a81a/3